# Knockout JS: How do you choose which object to bind to?

Tags: knockout.js

If I have 2 different JS objects on a page, both having a property called "name", and I do:

```
<span data-bind="text:name"></span>
```

How can I tell Knockout which object to bind to?

Comment: Are you calling ko.applybindings twice, with 2 different objects? Are the sections to apply the bindings scoped in some way, like each one in their own <div>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you are supposed to have one view model that you apply all bindings to:

```
    ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel);
```

So you need to decide which of your objects you want to make a view model. If you need both, you can make them subobjects of your model:

```
var objectOne = {name: "Object One"};
var objcetTwo = {name: "Object Two"};

var viewModel = {objectOne: objectOne, objectTwo: objectTwo};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html:

```
<span data-bind="text: objectOne.name"></span>
<span data-bind="text: objectTwo.name"></span>
```